# Could not install 'pip install pipenv' on windows 10 due to ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2]

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, python-3.10, pipenv-install

I could not install pipenv by using "pip install pipenv" It always says "ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Python310\Scripts\pipenv.exe' -> 'C:\Python310\Scripts\pipenv.exe.deleteme'"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV6KZ.png)

it also says like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJm6H.png)

I already added the "C:\Users\leira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts" and "C:\Users\leira\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages" to User and System Environmental paths. I don't know what else to do. Please help. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Run the terminal as an administrator or if you are on windows, run

```
python -m pip install pipenv
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks but it still says "'pipenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install --user pipenv
```